# Should I bulk up or keep cutting fat?

Tags: weightlifting, weight-loss, weight-gain

I'm hitting gym for 6 months, When I started I had about 20% of body fat, I was a skinny guy with big fat belly.
Now after 6 months of weight training and cardio I reduced body fat to 14% without lossing or gaining weight and I a have a better upper body.

Now I like to put on 5kg (11.5lbs) and I want to reduce body fat to 10%. My current wieght is 65kg (143Lbs).

1) Should I keep reducing my body fat, and once its reaches 10% start caloric excess diet?

or

2) Should I start a caloric excess diet and gain weight, once I reach my goal cut the fat to 10%?

3) If I do second approach, will I gain more body fat on weight gain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR: You should eat a small caloric surplus and lift heavy weights.**

If you cut down to 10% bodyfat now, and start adding calories later to gain mass, you will also increase your bodyfat again. Even if it won't be a lot of fat, you will also gain some fat.

It would be best to have a small caloric surplus, let's say about 200-300 calories above the amount of calories you need to stay on your current weight. This will allow you to gain mass while not overdoing it and gaining a lot of fat while doing so.

You should also hit big lifts, and hit them heavy. Don't just do isolation movements at 12 reps, this won't make you grow as effectively as a natural lifter. Combine heavy weight and low reps on compound movements with lower weight and high reps on isolation movements so you will gain muscle and burn calories during the workout as well (things like deadlifts actually burn quite a lot of calories).

**Example**: when training legs, do 5 sets of 5 reps on squats, after that, do things like lunges or leg extensions for 4 sets of 8-10 reps.

**Example 2**: when training back, do 5 sets of 5 reps on deadlifts, after that, do things like pull-ups, rows, lat-pulldown for 4 sets of 8-10 reps.

I hope it helps, it definitely helped me.

Comment: Please avoid swearing, we have all ages that participate here.

Comment: @JohnP Oh my bad, apologies!

Comment: 5x5 heavy deadlifts is really stupid. I can't think of a single respected program that recommends that. Your form will suffer and you put yourself at serious risk of injury. If you're seriously doing 5x5 with good form, you're not lifting enough

Comment: @Michael true. Even stronglifts 5x5 limits the dl to 1x5.

Comment: @Michael Depends on what you think are heavy deadlifts. I'm not saying try to do your 1RM 5 reps per set.. Doing 5x5 compound lifts is well known for giving great results.

Comment: @JBM I thought that'd be obvious as your one rep max is your *one rep* max. Yes but, as John said, even SL doesn't recommend 5x5 DLs and the entire program is based around doing 5x5.

Comment: @Michael Well I guess we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: You can do whatever you like but when you give others potentially dangerous advice, I have to call you out on it. The [consensus seems to be](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/26112/when-is-5x5-deadlifts-too-much-volume) that it's, at best, not optimal - ["Pulling heavy for 5×5 is brutal. Instead of accelerating your progress, you’ll slow it by missing reps more"](https://stronglifts.com/5x5/) - and at worst actively dangerous.

Comment: @Michael Right, when I do that please tell me so, but I've been deadlifting 5x5 (also tried 1x5 and 3x5) for a while now and found great results, recording my sets along the way to make sure my form is correct. I'm not giving dangerous advice, as long as your form and posture is correct you won't hurt yourself even if you do 20 reps.