# Will this workout build strong muscles for an intermediate bodybuilder?

Tags: weightlifting, workout-routines, strength, cardio, muscle-gain

So if I go to the gym 5 days a week and do this sort of workout with about 1700 calories a day, healthy diet with a mesomorph bodytype and about 8.5 hours of sleep each night, will this routine build your muscles up a lot stronger?

- Monday-45. min weights(Chest), 30 min. cardio(biking)
- Tuesday-45 min. weights(Back), 30 min. cardio(biking)
- Wednesday-45 min. weights(Legs), 30 min. cardio(biking)
- Thursday-45 min. weights(Biceps), 30 min. cardio(biking)
- Friday-45 min. weights(Delts), 30 min. cardio(biking)
- Weekend-Rest

I am asking this question because I have heard from some people that once a week for each muscle group isn't enough work and from others that it is just fine. Is this a good workout?

Comment: 1700 calories, this can't be real right? Right? Mind telling us your stats(your height and weight) and the actual routine, this include the exercises sets and reps. With that said, looking at this simple routine, this is probably not an optimal training method.

Comment: In my opinion, 5 days per week of aerobics is too much given the amount of calories you are consuming.  Of course, that would change if you are a competitive bodybuilder and are prepping for competition.  As for a routine, do what works for you and your goals (eg. bodybuilding).  There's no one perfect routine.

Answer (score 3):

You should use [a real strength training program with proven results](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/24596/7091). You probably aren't eating enough calories, and probably not enough protein. Your body needs to [recover](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19321/how-long-does-it-take-for-muscles-to-recover/19322#19322).

Especially if you get on a better program, your caloric needs will go up a lot.

I would advise staying away from body building routines in general: they're a terrific way to get tendinitis, imbalances, and not really get that strong. Even if you want to be a body builder, I'd recommend getting at least to the [intermediate stage in your squat, deadlift, and press](http://www.exrx.net/Testing/WeightLifting/StrengthStandards.htm).

Doing a real strength program will have you stronger, and even just looking at hypertrophy, you'll be using bigger weights which causes more growth.

Answer (score 1):

The general rule for increasing muscle growth is that you want to hit each muscle about twice a week, while also adjusting for recovery. If you need a source on good plans for building muscle, this youtube is very helpful: https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC68TLK0mAEzUyHx5x5k-S1Q (Jeff Nippard)

General Ideas for lifting to get stronger is that you need enough food (especially protein) to build muscle, start with compound lifts (squat, bench, deadlift/pull ups or rows) so you can lift the heaviest at the beginning of your workouts and then do more isolated exercises to finish off. Finally, the most important thing about lifting is just being consistent. If you are at 110% intensity every time you go, it will be hard to motivate yourself every day, whereas if you get in the habit of going every day (or five days a week) your progress will be what motivates you and you WILL see progress if you are consistent.