# Under What Conditions Will Muscles End Up Weaker After Work Out?

Tags: strength-training, recovery

A very, very common situation for me is this - I work out, I rest, I come back weaker. A number of books/people have given reasons for this:

1. Not enough sleep.
2. Not enough protein.
3. Frequency too high.

Etc. Can we get a comprehensive list of the factors (both behavioral and genetic)? Also, I would like to know what happens when a muscle can't repair itself over the short term. What happens in the long term?

Edit: I am really interested in the question overall, specifically in terms of what genetic potential is. Btw, I have read Supertraining (years ago), so I am familiar with the graph in the comments.

---

Anyway, my particular situation looks like this:

*7-8 hours of sleep weekdays, work ALL day in front of computer - 10-12 hrs
*Workouts look like AxxBxxA
*I walk a couple of miles on off-days and do hollow body holds / hip flexor stretches and some grip work, but it's light

A:
3 mile run @ 9min/mile
3 x 17 push ups (full ROM/control)
3 x 17 hanging leg raises
5 x 5 bench @ 185 lbs
5 x 5 row @ 135 lbs
3 x 20 bw squats

B
3 mile run @ 9min/mile
Bunch of core stuff - supermans, planks, etc
Calf raises, reverse calf raises (3 x 40 bw)
Quad/Ham machine 3x8 @ light weight
OHP 5 x 5 @ 125
PU 5 x 7 @ bw (200 lbs)

I have been working out for far over decade (in my mid 20s). I have been lifting  seriously for maybe 2 years. My bench was 5 x 5 at 225 lbs earlier this year. I didn't stop, I didn't change anything, I just keep getting weaker. I eat adequately.

Edit 2: Reading my own post I would be tempted to reply "Check if you are sick" - but the bench number is the only one that's dropping. OHP went up in the past few months, for example. This is also not the first time this happened. I have had a few more experiences like this with things like deadlift, where I progress, progress, and then suddenly numbers start dropping with no apparent cause (Happened around 5x5 @ 3.5 plate on DL). Btw, squat and DL aren't in the program due to muscle imbalance that I am fixing atm.

Comment: A comprehensive list is a bit broad. Maybe narrow this down by specifying your situation? What lifts, what sets and reps and weights, what days of the week, with what diet, and a description of your sleep and stresses.

Comment: related (but not a duplicate): http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/19322/7091

Comment: I am interested in the topic overall, but posted my details.

Comment: What were your push-ups like six months ago? Were they 3x17 then too?

Comment: 3x15 or something along those lines (I only record numbers for main lifts). I do them before bench and don't place emphasis on them except being sure I don't lose them. I can maybe do 3x20 with good form.

Comment: What happens when these lifts drop? Do you fail the last rep, do you hurt yourself, do you not have the energy to do the set at all, do you chicken out? How is your pre-workout ritual, and how have your energy levels been generally and during each workout?

Comment: Whoa, I just saw the 3 mile run for warm-up. Has that changed at all in pace, environment, or feeling? Have you tried a shorter run before a 5RM attempt on bench?

Comment: Oh, and how about form in the bench press? Did you switch your stance, set-up, or the standards you hold yourself to? I lost forty pounds on my bench once when I stopped cheating with a back arch and bouncing reps.

Comment: And where do you work out? Are you *sure* it's always the same bar?

Comment: Performing pushups before bench press is a bad idea *(for strength purposes).* Since both exercises primarily work the same muscles, either the pushups would have made your arms sore, which would have an impact on your bench.

Comment: I will also advocate ***weightlifting before cardio.*** Warm up should be something relatively easy for about 5 mins; a 3-mile run warm-up won't help your strength gains..

Answer (score -1):

PART1

When somebody will provide You so called "comprehensive list of ..." (especially both behavioral and genetic) - how You will check if it's true?

If You really interested in the question You should look in special sources (start with manuals for the basics, then - research periodics to be on wave of the state of the art) and make (and update!!!) that list Yourself, because sports medicine & physiology is constantly evolving field.

Regarding You question answer IMHO should be not general but specific - EXPERIMENT! For example for 1-2 week try to add 1 additional rest day /or/ make less approaches.

By the way - You tagged Your question as 'strength-training', but IMHO 3x5 & 5x17 regime is for endurance, not for strength.

PART 2 (links with removed http)

first: sorry for my English - is not my native, so I'd like to explain my point of view below

second: my knowledge on fitness is based on my experience as application for martial arts (...and long time ago when I was young and pretty) but I had no with this general scheme
or 
speedendurance.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/strength-muscle-mass-and-endurance_thumb.jpg - but it's just GENERALISATION of knowledge on reps...
unfortunately, man's (and muscle - as part of) life (and ) is very complex - for that reason complex (systematic) approad must be applied
scienceofsportsperformance.wordpress.com/2013/01/18/etsu-coches-sports-science-college-part-3/

As a consequence I agree with Joe Wider principles
bodybuilding.com/fun/remembering-joe-weider-the-science-of-the-weider-principle.html - You need

so... if in general You are not satisfied with situation, IMHO that means broken adaptation 
pponline.co.uk/encyc/img/270afig2.png
for more see
fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/19321/how-long-does-it-take-for-muscles-to-recover/19322#19322

first - what is Your task? where you want to be?
speedendurance.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/strengthendurance-continuum-SEC.jpg
what is your score
realfitscore.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/score-comparisons-v1.png

do you wanna be (kidding) as 
Hulk/gorilla 
muscleandfitness.com/sites/muscleandfitness.com/files/styles/full_node_image_1090x614/public/media/bodybuilder-brazil.jpg
muscleandfitness.com/incredible-hulk-program
or 
SWAT OPERATOR / 24/7-fit tactical athlete
cms.bbcomcdn.com/fun/images/2015/8-weeks-to-tactical-fitness-graphics-1.jpg
bodybuilding.com/fun/8-weeks-to-tactical-fitness.html

do You have strategy in terms of periodization?
img.breakingmuscle.com/sites/default/files/imagecache/full_width/images/bydate/201411/periodization-table.jpg
for more see 
scienceofsportsperformance.wordpress.com/2014/03/06/periodization-and-programming-for-strength-power-sports/

what aproach or theory You use 
scienceofsportsperformance.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/periodization-theory-and-methodology-of-training/

and how You do testing and planning
mmatrainingbible.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/testing-assigning-training-loads-reps-fig-18-2.jpg

how you mix (or don't mix at all) cardio- and resistance training
wikiliikkuja.com/2014/09/02/does-simultaneous-cardio-and-resistance-training-compromise-training-adaptations/

You should check more factors to diagnose OTS 
irunfar.com/2013/09/overtraining-syndrome-part-one.html
and do early health check/assesment (with all classic/basic tests and measures)

to really understand wha'ts is going on woith You braoder information must be collected and observe (kind of 
cpsinmotion.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Example_Periodisation_20142015.jpg.png
more on that
strengtheory.com/complete-strength-training-guide/

- Body composition
- Aerobic conditioning
- Nutrition / Bodybuilding nutrition consultant Jim Juge says nutrition determines your success or failure, plain and simple. "The diet is 65% of what you need to get in shape," he says. muscleandfitness.com/nutrition/meal-plans/28-days-lean-meal-plan
- Lifestyle factors.
  ...

Comment: 3x5 is for endurance? How do you figure?

Comment: @Alec he is simply incorrect, 3x5 is for strength, besides, notice that he only has one reputation

Comment: @RobSterach - Simply because a user is low rep, doesn't mean that they are ignorant. He may be incorrect here, but that isn't because he "only has 1 rep".

Comment: @RobSterach - So did you at one point. But that didn't mean what you said was incorrect. I'd rather encourage him to explain, than just dismiss everything outright, if it contradicts my current understanding. Ease up.

Comment: @Alec: He is just wrong if we go by any published material. Not much else to say. Sure, some will advocate sets of 3 reps for pure strength, but that's rather extreme.

Comment: @VSO - Yup, that's my understanding as well. But again, my point is that correlating that to someone's reputation is a weak correlation at best. And also, my endeavour to ask for elaboration here is being thoroughly reamed. I mean, he was right about the 5x17 thing.

Comment: Oh. sure, I just do those for maintenance though. And I agree with you on rep.

Comment: arguments ad homini is bad tone... but understandable - it jus shows your way of thinking (probalby in this case plays power of muscles, not brains)...

Comment: it's well known 

http://www.strengtheory.com/the-new-approach-to-training-volume/
recommendation that 1-5 reps is for building strength, 8-12 reps is for increasing muscle size, and 15-20 reps is for increasing muscular endurance
Finally, Brad Schoenfeld, my current favorite exercise researcher, published a meta-analysis...>>>

but I agree my mistake was interpretating authors "3x15 or something along those lines" and missign clarification in words "3x5 & 5x17 regime is for endurance, not for strength."

Comment: @VSO: have You red Principles of Strength Training by Viktor Seluyanov? One of the main points with Seluyanov’s work is that training is not just for the muscles but all systems in the body (anatomy, histology, biochemistry, physiology, endocrine, immune, etc) — even going as far as creating a new field of [scientific study called “Sports Adaptology”. see:] (https://trainadaptevolve.com/understanding-seluyanov/) Point Seluyanov makes — [there is no such thing as General Endurance, Speed Endurance, and Strength Endurance.] (http://www.8weeksout.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=296)

Comment: @AndriuZ: I have not, I will look into it.

Answer (score -1):

There is a string of possibilities here. They include:(please forgive the informally written list)

- The cardio is killing your gains in muscle
- You have a fast metabolism and have to eat even more
- You just aren't eating enough, even if you think you are and even if 
  you don't have a fast metabolism
- You have a medical problem or injury you should address with your
  doctor
- You are doing too much lightweight, bodyweight, and aerobic exercise
  instead of doing heavier weights
- You are suffering from severe stress
- You think you are getting weaker, but it is all in your head
- You are denying your legs and arms and are only working your chest,
  back, shoulders, and abs instead of working the limbs we need to use
  to help build those parts. Weak triceps=Low bench press
- You were shooting steroids, but stopped
- You lost weight making the bench press harder
- You are not training often enough
- You were using improper form, but changed it to proper form

Comment: This is just throwing spaghetti at the wall. There is no reasoning behind this other than personal guessing.

Comment: @John P I don't know what else you expect(not to be rude), judging by the fact he leaves out important details and puts in ones that don't even really matter. What is he eating? When is he eating? Where is he sleeping? When is he sleeping? If you insist on a more general answer, he is most likely either having some problem in his diet and/or sleeping habits. I also forgot to mention, maybe he is eating a lot of junk? I guess that my answer doesn't pinpoint anything exactly, but when a question isn't detailed enough, the asker can't be expecting lobster for dinner.

Comment: I expect that if he leaves out details and includes ones that don't matter, that you use the comment system as it is intended, and ask that he clarify. I don't expect that you just start guessing random crap and throwing it up as an answer. If you feel the question is too poor to salvage, downvote and vote to close.

Comment: My amount of sleep is and was in the post. I said I eat well, in terms of both protein and nutrition overall. I would have mentioned if I did roids. My form is always strict. I didn't lose weight. I am already eating a surprlus for my bw. If I eat more I just get fat and it doesn't change anything strength wise. Also, this board is funny. But I guess it goes without saying since there aren't even good books on the subject. Back to guessing.

Comment: @VSO Are you eating at night? Are you working out before you eat? And how come if you're "getting weaker" you're not losing weight? If none of these sound familiar, you either have a sleeping problem or a health problem, if what you're describing is true.